# Using group_by() in dplyr for certain number of rows

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

In dplyr, is there a way to use group_by() not with a variable but group by a specific number of rows? I am using SQLite with dplyr and I don't think SQLite has windowing function.

Comment: It will be best to provide reproducible example - minimal input data and expected output.

Comment: The point of group_by is to group by a variable so if there is not a variable of that then no, but you could use mutate to add an id to each row based off  what ever number of rows you want and then group_by

Comment: You can group "on the fly" with dplyr too: `DT %>% group_by(g = rep(1:18, each = 140)) %>% summarise(m = mean(VAR))` using Michael's example data.

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks, I assumed this was the case, but, much like my Spanish, I'm far better at reading than writing `dplyr`; I've added yours to my answer for centrality to potential future googlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to group on-the-fly, which means passing an *ad hoc* variable to the grouper.

In `data.table`, this would be done by using `rep` in `by`:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(01394)
DT <- data.table(VAR = rnorm(2520))

DT[ , mean(VAR), by = rep(1:18, each = 140)]
#     rep           V1
#  1:   1  0.029683200
#  2:   2  0.150411987
#  3:   3  0.061912697
#  4:   4 -0.014229183
#  5:   5 -0.007305455
#  6:   6  0.003784550
#  7:   7  0.010941501
#  8:   8  0.032129151
#  9:   9 -0.036524921
# 10:  10  0.046986451
# 11:  11  0.075547228
# 12:  12 -0.079538420
# 13:  13 -0.099833001
# 14:  14 -0.065297462
# 15:  15 -0.020778063
# 16:  16  0.095983764
# 17:  17  0.095292230
# 18:  18  0.150405148
```

---

As per @docendodecimus, the `dplyr` equivalent is:

```
DT %>% group_by(g = rep(1:18, each = 140)) %>% summarise(m = mean(VAR))
```